# Cannot connect to Apache server in XAMPP (443 port)

Tags: apache, network-security

can't connect to my apache server as have this problem:

```
13:55:14  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
13:55:14  [main]    Windows Version: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
13:55:14  [main]    XAMPP Version: 1.8.2
13:55:14  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
13:55:14  [main]    Running with Administrator rights - good!
13:55:14  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
13:55:14  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
13:55:14  [main]    All prerequisites found
13:55:14  [main]    Initializing Modules
13:55:14  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:55:14  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
13:55:14  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:55:14  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:55:14  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:55:14  [main]    Enabling autostart for module "Apache"
13:55:14  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
13:55:14  [main]    Control Panel Ready
13:55:15  [Apache]  Autostart active: starting...
13:55:15  [Apache]  Problem detected!
13:55:15  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
13:55:15  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:55:15  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:55:15  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:55:15  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
13:55:16  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
13:55:18  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
13:55:18  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:55:18  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:55:18  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:55:18  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:55:18  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:55:18  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
13:55:18  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
13:57:09  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
13:57:11  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
13:57:11  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:57:11  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:57:11  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:57:11  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:57:11  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:57:11  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
13:57:11  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Looked at other answers, not much help. Tried to change the port in ssl config file, unticked the 80 and 443 port as alternatives in skype.

Output from console:

```
C:\windows\system32>netstat -a -n -o |findstr 443


TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    127.0.0.1:55443        127.0.0.1:55444        ESTABLISHED     5688
TCP    127.0.0.1:55444        127.0.0.1:55443        ESTABLISHED     5688
TCP    137.195.217.195:49765  217.69.138.96:443      ESTABLISHED     6396
TCP    137.195.217.195:49906  91.190.218.65:443      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:49933  217.121.239.186:443    TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:49934  109.226.143.173:443    TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:49941  82.238.69.143:443      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:49942  77.250.206.134:443     TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:50234  91.190.218.17:443      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:50369  46.118.72.191:443      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:50370  140.164.26.217:443     TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    137.195.217.195:50379  92.122.83.240:443      ESTABLISHED     5512
TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

Any suggestions on how to finally use XAMPP without problems? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using alternative ports? The log and the output seem to indicate the port is already in use via this message `Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!`.

Comment: Yep, I've written in the question section that I've tried to change the port in ssl config. Changed it to 444, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try change the settings of the process with pid 4 not to use port 443 or close it. If that's not an option try changing the apache port. Guide to change the port: http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp EDIT: accidentally posted the apache port change not the ssl here is a guide for ssl and apache: http://furqansindhu.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/change-apache-port-in-xampp/

Comment: I have mentioned that I already tried to change the port in my question. Anyway, I've sorted the problem now. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ssl port on xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf . Search for 443, change it for 4430 or any other you like. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem when running multiple copies of XAMPP or after closing and opening it a few times.

Basically, httpd.exe is remaining open in the background and holding the ports open. The error message seems to be generic in that it will simply say that it cant open port 80/443 even if you've changed it to something else.

It's possible that something else is using the ports you have specified. You can check this by running resmon.exe, going to the Network tab and reviewing the processes listed under the Listening Ports section. If you find a conflict then you either need to kill the process or change the port to something else that is free.

Follow the instructions below to kill the httpd.exe process on Windows 8...

1. Close XAMPP.
2. Launch Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>).
3. Click the Details tab.
4. find httpd.exe and select it.
5. Click End Task then confirm.
6. Start XAMPP.
7. Click Start on the services you want to start.